GA4 BigQuery SQL - replicating a categorical value to a common key
inside GA4 there is a session_id which is used to identify the set of events that a user has made on site, I am using a case function to define my location names so I can merge it with a dataset of organic lead goals for a client. The challenge is that there are conversion events that occur on sections of the site where the visitor is not under a locations directory, so I need to search for a location in the rows of data and apply it to the whole session if there is one. I am using a case function to assign when a page_location contains the '/location/...'. The next step is identifying the first non null value for a location and apply the location based on session_id so essentially:

Location meets case
Find first location value for each session.
Assign location value for each session on every row for that session.

I've been trying to accomplish this with the query below, with some help, but I must admit I am struggling validating my approach. Any help on validating what I am trying to do if it works would help significantly.
-- add create or overwrite table organic_leads_v5_step_2
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE bigquery-inspired-closets.organic_leads_report.organic_leads_v5_step_3 AS(
-- Create a Common Table Expression (CTE) to get the first non-null location_name for each session
WITH first_location_per_session AS (
  SELECT
    ga_session_id,
    location_name,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ga_session_id ORDER BY event_timestamp ASC) AS row_num
  FROM `bigquery.data`
  WHERE location_name IS NOT NULL
),

-- Select the first non-null location_name per session
location_key AS (
  SELECT
    ga_session_id,
    location_name AS location_name_key
  FROM first_location_per_session
  WHERE row_num = 1
)

-- Merge the location_name_key with the original data
SELECT
  original.*,
  PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m-%d',
        FORMAT("%s-%s-%s", 
        SUBSTR(original.event_date, 1, 4), 
        SUBSTR(original.event_date, 5, 2), 
        SUBSTR(original.event_date, 7, 2))) AS formatted_event_date,
  lk.location_name_key
FROM `bigquery.data` AS original
LEFT JOIN location_key AS lk
ON original.ga_session_id = lk.ga_session_id)

Here is a truncated example of what the data looks like:
page_location url.com/location/place
ga_session_id 12341234
event_name page_view
event_date 20230908
event_timestamp 1694171148103529
session_source google
session_medium organic
session_campaign (not set)

just checking that you know that ga_session_id is a timestamp of when your user started the session and is not unique to a user
